# Exchange 2016 CU6 services not starting on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, exchange, service, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I am trying to run Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2016. After a clean install following the two articles [Install Exchange 2016 in Windows Server 2012 R2](http://www.mustbegeek.com/install-exchange-2016-in-windows-server-2012-r2/) & [Installing Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2016 Step by Step](http://www.careexchange.in/installing-exchange-2016-on-windows-server-2016-step-by-step/). There are two Windows Server 2016 VMs running under Hyper-V, one is the ADDC (with 4GB RAM and plenty of CPU provisioned) and the other is running Exchange 2016 (with 8GB RAM and plenty of CPU provisioned) installed from [Cumulative Update 6 for Exchange Server 2016 (KB4012108)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55520)
 on the Microsoft website. These are both two-day old installations with nothing different done during installation then instructed by the articles. All Windows and Exchange updates have been installed to date.

After a clean restart of the Exchange Server, Server Manager dashboard had red flags on 29 stopped services, most of which being Exchange-related services including the `Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology` service.

[image: Server Manager Dashboard screenshot]
[image: Stopped services screenshot]

From what I can see in Event Viewer, the MSADT service failed to start because the depandancy `NetTcpPortSharing` service failed to start because "`The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`"

[image: NetTcpPortSharing error Event Viewer screenshot]

I cannot see anything in Event Viewer relating to the `NetTcpPortSharing` service start failure (Other errors in screenshot are just Exchange services failing to start because the MSADT dependancy service was not running).

Any ideas?

Thanks

## Update

After a bit of looking around I noticed the Windows Firewall turned itself back on for the new Domain network profile when AD was set up...

Disabling the Windows Firewall again and restarting both machines got it down to 8 Exchange-related services not starting:

[image: Updated stopped services screenshot]

Comment: Do you have IPv6 protocol enabled as well as IPv4? Since it is a default installation and assuming you have followed the correct steps, there isn't any reason to have those services not starting. Does your Exchange 2016 server communicates properly with the Domain Controller? Is the time configured to use your DC as PDC/NTP?

Comment: Thanks for your response! The Exchange server was joined to the domain run by the ADDC as a member before Exchange was installed. I was able to log in on the Exchange server as the domain administrator account. If there are any other tests to check communication with the DC, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the Windows Firewall had turned itself back on when AD was set up. Now down to 8 Exchange services not starting.

Comment: You are welcome. In such cases, you have to go thoroughly through Event Viewer logs on the problematic server so you can have a better understanding of what's going on. Each service that fails to start should have a corresponding event containing a description of the issue or the issue it self that led the service to fail. Give it a try.